# Xamarin Android: TaskCanceledException when using HttpClient with Authentication

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, mono, azure-mobile-services

I have a rather specific problem, that only appears when a Android device is connected to the internet via a wifi hotspot created by a Huawei P8 Lite.

**This problem doesn't occur when the device is connected to the net via any other way!**

Whenever I try to connect to a https endpoint with an Azure AD Bearer Token in the Header my request times out after 100 seconds, caused by a exception in the mono network stack:

```
{System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
...
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x004c1] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:391
```

This is my code:

```
var mAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{APP-TENANT}");
var uri = new Uri("https://{APP-URL}/.auth/login/done");
var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(this);
var authResult = await mAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync("{APP-RESOURCE-ID}", "{APP-CLIENT-ID}", new Uri("https://{APP-URL}/.auth/login/done"), platformParams);
var token = authResult.AccessToken;

using (var _client = new HttpClient())
{
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://{APP-URL}");
    
    // Exception is thrown at this point
    var result = await _client.GetStringAsync("tables/beleg");
}
```

- The problem doesn't occur when I manually connect and sign in to my app url in Google Chrome before I send my request
- The problem doesn't occur when I'm using the ModernHttpClient instead of the default HttpClient, but this isn't possible because I'm using the Azure Mobile App Service Client, which always uses a default HttpClient for all login calls
- The problem doesn't occur when I successfully connect to my service with the ModernHttpClient once before using the default HttpClient

[Full Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/stefffdev/6e9d7589f110e2886d3dd5c514425eba)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, ever find the cause?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but as this problem only occured on the Huawei P8 Lite the customer replaced his Huawei phones with a different model.